# Ways to navigate grid with path restriction

Tags: combinatorics

I want to go from $(0,0)$ to $(8,8)$ in this $8\times8$ grid. I can only move up or right.

[image: grid]

However, I have to avoid the points $(3,3), (3,4), (4,3), (4,4)$ ($a,b,c,d$ in the figure). How many distinct paths are possible?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: We are not here to blindly answer your homework questions. You are more likely to get answers if you show what you have already tried first.

Comment: This is the third time in a short while that this has been asked – what's the source?